# Is it possible to align a child of a relative layout centered on top of another child?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a relative layout that contains some text views and a (circular) image view with the image view centered in the middle.

There is an animation of expanding rings emanating from center of the relative layout, which as the image view is also centered also emanates from the center of the image view.

However now there is a requirement to shift vertically up the image view a bit so its not longer in the center of the layout, and thus the origin of the animations need to also shift vertically by the same degree.

Here's a sketch of how the animation is implemented, its only showing a small portion of the code to show the main features of its implementation.

```
public class RippleBackground extends RelativeLayout {
private ArrayList<RippleView> rippleViewList=new ArrayList<RippleView>();
    private Paint paint;
    private AnimatorSet animatorSet;
    private ArrayList<Animator> animatorList; 

        ...
        paint = new Paint();
        rippleParams=new LayoutParams((int)(2*(rippleRadius+rippleStrokeWidth)),(int)(2*(rippleRadius+rippleStrokeWidth)));
        rippleParams.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, TRUE);

        animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animatorList=new ArrayList<Animator>();
        addView(rippleView,rippleParams);
        rippleViewList.add(rippleView);

        ...
        animatorSet.playTogether(animatorList);


    private class RippleView extends View {
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int radius=(Math.min(getWidth(),getHeight()))/2;
            canvas.drawCircle(radius,radius,radius-rippleStrokeWidth,paint);
        }
    }
```

This is how its implemented currently, I was wondering if I could just do something like replace `rippleParams.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, TRUE)` with some other rule, but I can't see any other rule that would be applicable.

I was wondering if its possible to use a rule to align the animation view so its no longer centered on the parent RelativeLayout but on the imageView which is within the RelativeLayout?

Or is it possible to specify the co-ordinates, or some other way I can move the origin point of the animations up to match the imageView center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you, I can't see how you can do it with a simple rule, but what you could do is wrap your `RippleView` in a `FrameLayout` with some `paddingBottom` on it that matches the amount your `ImageView` is moved up from the centre by.

If, for example, your `ImageView` is now `100dp` up from the centre of your `RelativeLayout`, you'd also set `paddingBottom` to `100dp` on the new `FrameLayout` wrapping your `RippleView`  To make it clearer what I mean, here's the XML layout that would achieve it (I've only used XML as I think it's clearer what's going on, and I'm confident you're able to easily translate it to do it programmatically in your code):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="#f00"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've added background colours to the `FrameLayout` and the `ImageView` (which in your case would be your `RippleView`) so you can clearly see their bounds - note that the `ImageView` is fully contained in the `FrameLayout`:

[image: Screen Shot]

Another option would be to put your `ImageView` and your `RippleView` in a `FrameLayout` which is set to `wrap_content` for width and height, then position the `FrameLayout` where you would have put the `ImageView` and set `layout_gravity="center" on your`RippleView`, so that the`RippleView`ends up centred on the`ImageView`by virtue of the fact the bounds of the`FrameLayout`match the bounds of the`ImageView` - e.g.:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="#f00"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/rippleView"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screen Shot 2]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these.